# htop output to human readable file

Tags: formatting, ascii, human-readable, htop

I've tried piping `htop` to a text file (e.g. `htop > text.txt`) but it gives me text garbled by formatting strings (see below).  Is there a way to get nicer, human readable output?

```
^[7^[[?47h^[[1;30r^[[m^[[4l^[[?1h^[=^[[m^[[?1000h^[[m^[[m^[[H^[[2J^[[1B  ^[[36m1  ^[[m^[[1m[^[[m^[[32m||||||||||^[[31m||||||||||^[[30m^[[1m                                                            \
     22.2%^[[m]^[[m     ^[[36mTasks: ^[[1m159^[[m^[[36m total, ^[[32m^[[1m5^[[m^[[36m running^[[3;3H2  ^[[m^[[1m[^[[30m                                                                                \
      0.0%^[[m]^[[m     ^[[36mLoad average: ^[[30m^[[1m1.11 ^[[m^[[m1.28 ^[[1m1.31 ^[[4;3H^[[m^[[36m3  ^[[m^[[1m[^[[m^[[32m||||||||||^[[30m^[[1m                                                       \
                    11.1%^[[m]^[[m     ^[[36mUptime: ^[[1m9 days, 22:04:51^[[5;3H^[[m^[[36m4  ^[[m^[[1m[^[[30m                                                                                      0.0\
%^[[m]^[[6;3H^[[m^[[36m5  ^[[m^[[1m[^[[m^[[31m||||||||||^[[30m^[[1m                                                                           11.1%^[[m]^[[7;3H^[[m^[[36m6  ^[[m^[[1m[^[[30m           \
```

Answer (score 73):

htop author here.

No, there's no "nice" way to get the output of htop piped into a file. It is an interactive application and uses terminal redraw routines to produce its interface (therefore, piping it makes as much sense as, for example, piping vim into a text file -- you'll get similar results).

To get the information about your processes in a text format, use "ps". For example, `ps auxf > file.txt` gives you lots of easy to parse information (or `ps aux` if you do not wish tree-formatting -- see `man ps` for more options).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm specifically trying to find usage per processor --- which htop does so nicely.  Is there a way to access this via `ps`?

Comment: thanx, but man make an export to some file to make the thing more usable

Comment: +1 Hi Hisham, htop has no switch -b :) , I'd like to use it this way for output without menu line: htop -b | aha --black

Comment: htop shows the approximate % of cpu core spending in kernel (e.g. red).  that's something ps can't provide.  Hence, it would be great htop could be dumped to a file.

Answer (score 28):

htop outputs [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to use colors and move the cursor around the terminal. There is a great command line program [aha](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/aha.1.html) that can be used to convert ANSI into HTML.

**Ubuntu/Debian installation**

```
apt-get install aha
```

**Save htop output as HTML file**

```
echo q | htop | aha --black --line-fix > htop.html
```

Comment: For an example using ansi2html.sh see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10323333 and linked there is a feature request to add a -b option to htop to make batch processing simpler

Comment: Why do we need `echo q` at the start? Tried without that and got extra text at the end of the file. UPDATE: To quit `htop` right?

Comment: If you want `htop` to display as if it's running at a specific terminal size, you can do something like `LINES=32 COLUMNS=80 htop`

Answer (score 17):

I have had the same need, and ended up using `top` instead of `htop` a is provides a batch mode via the `-b` flag.

> -b : Batch mode operation
>   Starts top in 'Batch mode', which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file.  In this mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the '-n' command-line option or until killed.

So for example:

```
top -b -n 1
```

Hope this helps even if this is not using `htop`.

Answer (score 8):

This command outputs plain text. (It requires installing `aha` and `html2text`.)

```bash
echo q | htop -C | aha --line-fix | html2text -width 999 | 
grep -v "F1Help\|xml version=" > file.txt
```

Comment: How is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224271/230468?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix This give to you result in clean text whitout any html tags.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Forgot add output command. Edited right now. Did you try? This is what you need? :)

Answer (score 1):

Install recode first, then encode it to utf-8:

```
$htop | recode utf-8 > test.txt
```

Then cat the file and you should be good.

Comment: might be good as a workaround, but when I've tried it, it failed to grab all the process list, and always displayed just a subset, not a reliable way to get the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use script prior to running htop in a mode that will redirect timings to a file for later playback. In the realm of 'yet another work around' and 'good for show and tell'.

```
script -t -a /var/tmp/script.htop.out 2> /var/tmp/script.htop.out.timings
htop
```

Then to playback

```
scriptreplay /var/tmp/script.htop.out.timings /var/tmp/script.htop.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answers, I suggest use python to do some post-processing. The codes are as follows:

First, we get the text from htop:

```
echo q | htop -C > a.txt
```

Then, we use python to make it human-readable:

```py
import re
htop = open("a.txt").read()
print(re.sub(r'\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])', "", re.sub(r"\x1b\[\d\d;\dH|\x1b\[\d;3H", "\n", '\n'.join(htop)))[9:])
```

The results are as follows:

```
1  [                          0.0%]   Tasks: 11, 38 thr; 1 running
2  [                          0.0%]   Load average: 0.38 0.26 0.11 
3  [                          0.0%]   Uptime: 01:19:50
4  [                          0.0%]
Mem[|#****              700M/25.5G]
Swp[                         0K/0K]
    PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command        
     51 root       20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 /tools/node/bin
52 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.21 /tools/node/bin
53 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.19 /tools/node/bin
54 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.16 /tools/node/bin
55 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.15 /tools/node/bin
56 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 /tools/node/bin
57 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.05 /tools/node/bin
58 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.04 /tools/node/bin
59 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.05 /tools/node/bin
60 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.04 /tools/node/bin
1 root20   0  359M 62880 33428 S  0.0  0.2  0:08.76 /tools/node/bin
16 root20   0 35892  4768  3660 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.62 tail -n +0 -F /
75 root20   0  190M 61096 13512 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python
76 root20   0  190M 61096 13512 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.56 /usr/bin/python
F1Help  F2Setup F3SearchF4FilterF5Tree  F6SortByF7Nice -F8Nice +F9Kill  F10Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

This method retains all colors in htop while saving output, and requires no additional libraries:

To save the output to file (with 10 secs refresh rate):

```
watch -n 10 "timeout 5 htop -d 100 > htop.log"
```

If you want the command to fully run in background:

```
COLUMNS=$COLUMNS LINES=$LINES nohup watch -n 10 "timeout 5 htop -d 100 > htop.log" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Note: Feel free to change the refresh rates by modifying the seconds in the watch & the timeout command. The time specified in watch should be greater than timeout, and the htop -d parameter (refresh rate in 1/10th of a sec) should be >= watch seconds * 10.

In order to read the color output, and display on screen (with auto refresh):

```
tail -f htop.log
```

Answer (score -1):

This may sound really noobish, however, if you have multiple monitors you could have htop running while "record my desktop" is capturing that area. Its more of a video and may not help with searching and sorting but it would look nice and pretty.