# running a program through ssh fails with "Error opening terminal: unknown."

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, ssh, pipe

When I try to execute a simple command through ssh, then it is successful. e.g.

```
#] ssh servername "echo abcd"
abcd
#]
```

However, when I try the following command, it fails:

```
#] ssh servername  ~/htopmem.sh
Error opening terminal: unknown.
#]
```

where the content of htopmem.sh is below. (inspired by the answer of Marwan Alsabbagh on [htop output to human readable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534591/htop-output-to-human-readable-file))

```
#!/bin/bash
echo q | htop | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | ~/aha --black --line-fix | grep Mem | grep -E -o "[0-9]+/[0-9]+"
```

If I manually ssh to the server and run htopmem, then the execution is successful:

```
#] ./htopmem.sh
6515/24021
#]
```

any idea on how to make the "ssh servername  ~/htopmem.sh" command work?

Thank you!

Comment: `htop` wants a terminal. have you checked the manual? There might be a switch...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A plain `ssh` command like that does not have a `tty` (terminal).  Use the `-t` option to force `ssh` to open the terminal on its way in.

From the [manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1):

> `-t`

> Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based    programs on a remote machine, which can     be
> very useful, e.g., when implementing menu services.  Multiple `-t`
> options force tty allocation, even  if ssh has no local tty.

So this would work (better):

```
ssh -t servername  '~/htopmem.sh'
```

Comment: If you use variables like `$HOME` or `~`, they need to be in single quotes to be interpreted by the remote server and not the local client.