# how to use [exec_command] to get remote server's htop outout to a file?

Tags: python, linux, shell

i run the command on a Linux server.it works well.

```
/usr/bin/echo q | /usr/bin/htop | /usr/local/bin/aha --stylesheet --line-fix >> htop.html
```

but i run remote command with python exec_command . it work not well.
the  html is blank.

```
client.exec_command("/usr/bin/echo q | /usr/bin/htop | aha --black --line-fix >> htop.html")
```

who can tell me the reason?

Comment: In the original command the `aha` binary is full path. Why in the python script you use relative?

Comment: thanks. i change aha binary to full path. but htop.html is still blank.

Comment: i have tried                                      
  client.exec_command("/path/htop.sh") . and htop.sh's content is /usr/bin/echo q | /usr/bin/htop | /usr/local/bin/aha --stylesheet --line-fix >> htop.html .                htop.html is still lank.

Comment: When I try executing your command, I get an empty file. Unless `aha` binary do something with the output so it becomes readable, you end up with empty file.

Comment: You might find this thread useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534591/htop-output-to-human-readable-file
 and you can use `top -b` which is `batch` mode that dumps the output wherever you need.