# Linux Terminal - Take screenshot of top command and email it

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, screenshot

I'm using *Ubuntu 14.04* in AWS, It doesn't have any Graphical UI, I want to implement an automated process that sends a screenshot of the `top` command whenever my CPU goes *>70%*.

And sometimes we need to send the output of `df -h`, `du -sh`, `htop`, *etc.*

The problem that I'm facing is, How to take a snapshot of a page without any GUI? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: As processing bitmap may use a lot of processor, think using *text only* monitoring!

Comment: Please clarify whether the output should be plain text ASCII, or can include terminal control codes.

Answer (score 4):

```
top -n 1 -b > top-output.txt
```

About option -b and -n from the top command man page:

```
    -b  :Batch-mode operation
        Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful  for  sending
        output  from  top  to  other  programs or to a file.  In this
        mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations
        limit  you've  set with the `-n' command-line option or until
        killed.

   -n  :Number-of-iterations limit as:  -n number
        Specifies  the  maximum  number of iterations, or frames, top
        should produce before ending.
```

**UPD**
[see this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194427/what-is-the-terminal-command-to-take-a-screenshot)

Comment: This is good for top, but sometimes we need to send the output of htop, df -h and du -sh, So it would be better if we have a screehshot. (updated in question)

Comment: These all required X server.

Comment: let's try `scrot`

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT 2021 about *`MacOS`*

## Don't use *screenshot* for monitoring!

A bit-mapped graphic screenshot needs to process a lot of bytes, compress them, and so on, using them for monitoring is a *not-so-good* idea!

Even when you read mail containing a screenshot, you won't be able to read values directly from your mail... (use of OCR tools with a lot of resources again)...

### About `top` syntax

Running `top` in ***batch*** mode for only ***one*** shot syntax is:

```
top -bn 1
```

Under MacOS, you will run:

```
top -l 1
```

For more info, feel free to hit `man top` in your console, then rtfm!

#### Send `top` by mail when cpu load become high

This little script will send `top` results, by mail, if the CPU load is over 70%, by using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). This could be run by `crontab`, for example...

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    declare -a out=()
    read; out+=("$REPLY")
    read; out+=("$REPLY")
    read; out+=("$REPLY")
    read foo user foo system foo <<<"$REPLY"
    ((tot=(${user//.}+${system//.}),tot>700))&& {
        tot=000$tot
        printf -v pct "%.1f\n" ${tot:0:${#tot}-1}.${tot:${#tot}-1}
        (
            printf "%s\n" "${out[@]}"
            cat
        ) |
        mail -s "$HOSTNAME's CPU load: $pct tot, $user us, $system sy!" user@host
    }
} < <(top -bn1);
```

This will read and store the 3 first lines of the `top` command, compute the total for *user* and *system* percents, then if that total is greater than 70%, render `$pct` for mail subject, then send the 3 stored lines and the rest of the `top` command, by using `cat` on *STDIN*.

... ( syntax `${user//.}` will drop the dot, then multiply by 10 output of `top` command) ...

Mac version of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    declare -a out=()
    for i in {1..4} ;do
        read; out+=("$REPLY")
    done
    read foo{,} user foo system foo <<<"${REPLY//%}"
    printf -v user %.2f $user
    printf -v system %.2f $system
    ((tot=(${user//.}+${system//.}),tot>7000))&& {
        tot=000$tot
        printf -v pct "%.2f\n" ${tot:0:${#tot}-2}.${tot:${#tot}-2}
        (
            printf "%s\n" "${out[@]}"
            cat
        ) |
        mail -s "$HOSTNAME's CPU load: $pct tot, $user us, $system sy!" user@host
    }
} < <(top -l1);
```

#### Send mail when **storage** becomes full

```
#!/bin/bash

{
    read headline
    declare -a over=()
    while read;do
        read filesys size use avail pct mpnt <<<"$REPLY"
        ((${pct%%%}>70)) && over+=("$REPLY")
    done

    ((${#over[@]}>0))&&{
        printf "%s\n" "$headline" "${over[@]}" |
        mail -s "$HOSTNAME: ${#over[@]} disks over limit!" user@host
    }
} < <(LANG=C df -h  / )
```

This will send a mail with subject: *"MyHost: N disks over limit!"* with `N` as number of disks, and content output of `df -h` for only *`N`* disks.

This script was tested under MacOS, seem work fine too!

In order to prevent useless values to be printed, you have to list devices you want to survey as `df` arguments:

```
...
} < <(LANG=C df -h  / /usr /home /etc )
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers solve most of the problem. [F.Hauri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129820/6136214) shows how to check for a condition, and send mail when required.  [Tso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46129598/6136214) shows how to dump `top` output to a file, which file can be sent as needed (as per *F. Hauri's* answer).

What remains:

`df -h` output can be redirected to a file like so `df -h > output1`.  Same with `du`, *i.e.* `du -h > output2`.

`htop` to plain text:  see [k0fe's answer to "*htop output to human readable file*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46024517/6136214).