# Run shell commands with imaginative display

Tags: php, shell, htop

I am trying to output htop output on my server as a viewable HTML page so I can check on it easily. I got the export to HTML part done already (using `echo q | htop | aha --black --line-fix`). This works perfectly fine when I'm using it interactively, and now what I needed to do is to connect it to a web portal. My setup is PHP, and I use `exec()` and `shell_exec()` to try to display the output. However, the output is blank. I suspect this is because there is no display that htop knows about, so it has no way of knowing what the correct dimension to display is. So my question is, is there a way to tell a generic process/shell script that it can use an imaginative display with specified dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The easiest way to do this is not using htop anymore. The author [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17551928/9577975) that htop is supposed to be used interactively, and that there is no easy way to get the output of it. Another monitoring tool with a built-in web server mode is [glances](https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/), and you can do something like `glances -w` and you are all set.

However, if you really want to do htop then I got that figured out. Simplest working code is:

```
echo shell_exec("export TERM=xterm-color;echo q | htop | aha --black --line-fix");
```

More customizable working code is:

```
exec("rm /var/www/html/abc");
exec("export TERM=xterm-color;echo Hthq | htop | aha --black --line-fix > /var/www/html/abc");
echo shell_exec("cat /var/www/html/abc | head -n 10");
echo shell_exec("cat /var/www/html/abc | tail -n 25");
```

This allows you to change settings around in the `echo Hthq` part. The final `hq` opens htop's help menu and then closes it, forces htop to redraw everything. The `head` and `tail` bits will cut out the correct segments. Everything before (like `Ht`, which hides threads and display tree view) you can customize.